# CakePHP concepts Components and Helpers in Symfony-2.0

Tags: cakephp, symfony

Are the CakePHP concepts [Components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component) and [Helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers) available in Symfony-2.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Symfony2 has its own components, and some of its features might be compared to the *helpers* you're asking about. You can also create yours.

Comment: Can you give me the name of the features?

Comment: Note about helpers (view): Symfony uses twig templating engine by default. You can extend it by using filters, functions and extensions: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Comment: @habeebperwad: `Helper::url()` -> Twig (`{{ url|escape('url') }}`) - `CacheHelper` -> The cache component - `FormHelper` -> The form component - `NumberHelper` -> Twig has that kind of features - `SessionHelper` -> Why the hell would one access the session from a view? :) You can access basic stuff such as the user role for example though - `TextHelper` -> Twig.